# Text to Speech Android Application Query

Tags: android

i want to build an application on Android platform that will convert text to speech for the text,documents,pdf files.  Multireader app. does the same thing.
is there any open source app. similar to this ?
i know  how to build text to speech for text ,but how to make it work for other file types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read those other file types and convert it to plain text. Then you take the plain text and read it. I am sure that there are open apis for pdf documents that allow you to read a document and extract the text.